# How is matter stored in black hole?

Tags: black-holes

A black hole engulfs the matter nearby, how does it store the mass inside? We know that matter is composed of particles, does a black hole store the mass in massive particles? Or can we assume that it's composed of extremal black holes? what are theories about it?

EDIT:
I checked out [Black-holes are in which state of matter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35150/black-holes-are-in-which-state-of-matter)
it doesn't provide a definite answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A black hole is created by stellar core collapse.  Its event horizon (if that exists -Hawking) appears.  By what mechanism and path, as viewed eternally, can accreted matter enter the black hole proper? It externally appears to be asymptotically stuck within the event horizon.

The inside of a black hole is speculative, certainly at the singularity (if there is one), for the unknown local geometry of spacetime.  Adding mass to a black hole linearly increases its external radius.  The external volume increases as the cube of the external radius, implying that galactic core supermassive black holes have average densities approaching zero. NGC 4889 is 2.1×10^10 solar masses, then $r = (2.95)(M/M_{sun})$ km.  The sun's average density is 1409 kg/m^3.  Calculate NGC 4889's average external density.

Consider a Kerr (rotating) black hole.  If mass resides in a central zero-dimensional singularity, what sources the external angular momentum?   $L= r × mv$.  Black hole interiors are not well-defined.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the info you provided is satisfactory. I took a look at [Kerr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_black_hole) it says that `A black hole in the Milky Way, GRS 1915+105, may rotate 1,150 times per second.` thrilling!

Comment: External observations are theoretically sound.  At the event horizon and beneath is elegant speculation.  You can look it up technically, http://arxiv.org/find/ and become educated without becoming informed. Science is forever fascinating - certainly at least until it works.

Comment: Archive in the link is a treasure. I'm digging in.

Comment: One more!  Black hole Official Truth is in vigorous debate, http://backreaction.blogspot.com/2014/02/can-planck-stars-exist.html.  Lubos Motl knows everything that should be true.  Sabine Hossenfelder explores a vast volume of what might be truer.  Interesting, both ways.

Comment: I just looked at the link, I wathced a documentary about if information gets lost  in black hole, it narrates the discussion between Susskind and Hawking. [the Hawking paradox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYXrzSw4CTE)